# I made a websocket application with .net, how can I connect this application with kotlin?

Tags: c#, android, .net, api, websocket

I made a websocket application with .net, how can I connect this application with kotlin?

How can I write an api to make the connection between .net and kotlin?

Program.cs :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Fleck;

namespace WebSocketConsole
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FleckLog.Level = LogLevel.Debug;
            var allSockets = new List<IWebSocketConnection>();
            var server = new WebSocketServer("ws://0.0.0.0:7080");
            server.Start(socket =>
            {
                socket.OnOpen = () =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("İstemci bağlantısı başarılı!");
                    allSockets.Add(socket);
                    Console.WriteLine("Mevcut istemci sayısı: " + allSockets.ToList().Count);
                };
                socket.OnClose = () =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("İstemci bağlantısı koptu!");
                    allSockets.Remove(socket);
                    Console.WriteLine("Mevcut istemci sayısı: " + allSockets.ToList().Count);
                };
                // Mesaj Teslim Alındığında
                socket.OnMessage = message =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(message);
                    allSockets.ToList().ForEach(s => s.Send(message));
                };
            });

            //giriş mesajını oku
            var input = Console.ReadLine();
            //When the message is not "exit", enter an infinite loop
            while (input != "exit")
            {
                //Tüm soket istemcilerini dolaş ve her istemciye mesaj gönder
                foreach (var socket in allSockets.ToList())
                {
                    socket.Send(input);
                }
                input = Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

htmlpage.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <div>Mesaj Gönder:</div>
 <input type="text" id="msgContent" />
 <input type="button" value="Gönder" onclick="CHAT.chat()" />
 <div>Gönderilen Mesaj:</div>
 <div id="receiveMsg" style="background-color: gainsboro;"></div>
 <script type="application/javascript">

          window.CHAT = {
              socket: null,
              init: function() {
                  if (window. WebSocket) {
                      CHAT.socket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:7080/ws");//websocket server address and port
                      CHAT.socket.onopen = function() {
                          console.log("Bağlantı başarıyla kuruldu...");
                      },
                      CHAT.socket.onclose = function() {
                          console.log("Bağlantı kesildi...");
                      },
                      CHAT.socket.onerror = function() {
                          console.log("Bir hata oluştu...");
                      },
                      CHAT.socket.onmessage = function(e) {
                          console.log("Received message: " + e.data);
                          var receiveMsg = document. getElementById("receiveMsg");
                          var html = receiveMsg. innerHTML;
                          receiveMsg.innerHTML = html + "<br/>" + e.data;
                      }
                  } else {
                      alert("Bu taryacı websocket protokolünü desteklemiyor...");
                  }
              },
              chat: function() {
                  var msg = document. getElementById("msgContent");
                  CHAT.socket.send(msg.value);

              }
          };

          CHAT.init();

 </script>
```

How can I make the connection with kotlin. For example, there will be an example button in kotlin, it will send a message when you click the button.